# Difficulties with Dart syntax to close UI Widget Tree Structures

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having a really tough time wrapping my head around building UI's in dart. Here's where I'm stuck:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,  // or use fixed size like 200
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: _center, zoom: 11.0))
    ]);
    }
}
```

I've tried closing this in a thousand different ways. I don't understand it. Is there some sort of plugin that'll do this for me? :/

Comment: it's not really clear, at least for me, what you're trying to achieve and what is your problem

Comment: The above is the end of my main.dart. I'm trying to compile it and display only the map. It won't compile because the end isn't closed properly. I'm confused by the structure of DART and how to close something like this. Any idea how?

Comment: paste the whole widget code please, I've already spotted some errors, but its better if you paste it all

Comment: Okay, I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You only have to use `;` to close the `return` widget. In this case the `Scaffold();`

Also, try to use `,` like I've used for the dart formatter help you indent this like mine.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                  .size
                  .width, // or use fixed size like 200
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 11.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```